# jquery identify which div is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 4 divs in one main div. No div has ID. now i want to identify which div is clicked by jquery.

Below is the html code I have.

```
    <div class="body">
        <div class="summery-item-widget">details 1</div>
        <div class="summery-item-widget">details 2</div>
        <div class="summery-item-widget">details 3</div>
        <div class="summery-item-widget">details 4</div>
    </div>
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It's **well worth** your time reading through [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com) from beginning to end. It only takes an hour or two, and it saves you that time almost immediately by giving you this information proactively.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `this` keyword in the event handler to reference the clicked element:

```js
$('.summery-item-widget').click(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  console.log(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body">
  <div class="summery-item-widget">details 1</div>
  <div class="summery-item-widget">details 2</div>
  <div class="summery-item-widget">details 3</div>
  <div class="summery-item-widget">details 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: alternatively, click will throw the event as argument into the callback. you could essentially get the click target through: `e.target` too

Comment: Small nit: `this` will refer to the element on which you hooked the click event. That will be the element clicked in this case, since the divs have no children, but in the general case could be an ancestor of the element clicked. (E.g., `this` is `event.currentTarget` rather than `event.target`.)

Answer (score 4):

This is what you need.

```
$(".summery-item-widget").click(function(){
   console.log(this)
});
```

`this` will return the element that you clicked.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this will help you.

```js
$('.summery-item-widget').click(function() {
    var val = $(this).text();
    alert(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body">
  <div class="summery-item-widget">details 1</div>
  <div class="summery-item-widget">details 2</div>
  <div class="summery-item-widget">details 3</div>
  <div class="summery-item-widget">details 4</div>
</div>
```